# Sorting k elements in one step

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have a problem and I'm not quite sure how to prove the following:

Assume you can sort *k* elements in a single step and no other operations are allowed. Prove that sorting *n* elements requires Omega((n log n)/(k log k)) steps.

I'm a little baffled with this problem. Can anyone please guide me on the correct path? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many comparisons are necessary to sort n elements? How many are sufficient to sort k?